# using chef extension in Azure for Ubuntu VM machines

Tags: ubuntu, azure, chef-infra

I am trying to use chef extension in azure with my own Chef server. Everything works if I do it through web portal. However, when I use resource management template, Chef failed with SSL certificate error.

I am following this template: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/chef-json-parameters-ubuntu-vm

Here is the properties for Chef extension:

```
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Chef.Bootstrap.WindowsAzure",
    "type": "LinuxChefClient",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1210.12",
    "settings": {
      "bootstrap_options": {
        "chef_node_name": "[concat(parameters('slaveChefNodeName'),copyIndex())]",
        "chef_server_url": "[parameters('chefServerUrl')]",
        "validation_client_name": "[parameters('chefValidationClientName')]"
      },
      "runlist": "[parameters('slaveRunlist')]"
    },
    "protectedSettings": {
      "validation_key": "[parameters('chefValidationKey')]"
    }
  }
```

here is the traceback from chef client:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error:   certificate verify failed
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
```

Just verified with a working node. The validation key is fine except the not working node validation file has an extra new line at the end of the file.

Thank you.

Update: I tried ssl_verify option and it didn't work. I have to stress that the vm works perfectly if I use Azure Portal to upload client.rb and validator.pem.

```
   "settings": {
      "client_rb": "ssl_verify_mode :verify_none\n",
      "bootstrap_options": {
        "chef_node_name": "[concat(parameters('slaveChefNodeName'),copyIndex())]",
        "chef_server_url": "[parameters('chefServerUrl')]",
        "validation_client_name": "[parameters('chefValidationClientName')]",
        "verify_ssl": "verify_none"
      },
      "runlist": "[parameters('slaveRunlist')]"
    },
```

Comment: Your new node do not know the server certificate (probably self signed), add a `"verify_ssl": "verify_none"` in the bootstrap_options and manage to distribute the server certificate with chef later before switching the ssl validation on again.

Comment: @Tensibai If I start a server with Azure Portal with chef extension enabled, everything will work. I can however bootstrap chef client with knife bootstrap with "sudo".

Comment: I was just commenting about the error you get, I've no clue how azure hide you what it does under the hood when you use the interface, so good luck with it...